# How optimize to avoid using too many ‘if’ ‘elif’ ‘else’ statements and effectively reduce cyclomatic complexity?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to judge the browser type and do something about it, but I checked and found **init** function cyclomatic complexity is (13).

I think this's because I'm using too many 'if' 'elif' 'else' statements.

### original function

```
def __init__(self, browser='ff', remote_address=None):
    """
    remote consle：
    dr = PySelenium('RChrome','127.0.0.1:8080')
    """
    t1 = time.time()
    dc = {'platform': 'ANY', 'browserName': 'chrome', 'version': '', 'javascriptEnabled': True}
    dr = None
    if remote_address is None:
        if browser == "firefox" or browser == "ff":
            dr = webdriver.Firefox()
        elif browser == "chrome" or browser == "Chrome":
            mobile_emulation = {"deviceName": "Galaxy S5"}
            option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            option.add_experimental_option('w3c', False)
            option.add_experimental_option('mobileEmulation', mobile_emulation)
            dr = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option)
            # dr = webdriver.Chrome()

        elif browser == "internet explorer" or browser == "ie":
            dr = webdriver.Ie()
        elif browser == "opera":
            dr = webdriver.Opera()
        elif browser == "phantomjs":
            dr = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        elif browser == "edge":
            dr = webdriver.Edge()
    else:
        if browser == "RChrome":
            dr = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://' + remote_address + '/wd/hub',
                                  desired_capabilities=dc)
        elif browser == "RIE":
            dc['browserName'] = 'internet explorer'
            dr = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://' + remote_address + '/wd/hub',
                                  desired_capabilities=dc)
        elif browser == "RFirefox":
            dc['browserName'] = 'firefox'
            dc['marionette'] = False
            dr = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://' + remote_address + '/wd/hub',
                                  desired_capabilities=dc)
```

I've thought about using the following approaches, but I feel like they don't apply to my situation

### optimization plan 1

```
def visit_a(self, ...):
    ...
    ...

def dispatch(self, value):
    method_name = 'visit_' + str(value)
    method = getattr(self, method_name)
    method()
```

### optimization plan 2

```
def function_1(...):
    ...

functions = {'a': function_1,
             'b': function_2,
             'c': self.method_1, ...}

func = functions[value]
func()
```

### questions:

How do I optimize '**init**' function to avoid using too many ‘if’ ‘elif’ ‘else’ statements and effectively reduce cyclomatic complexity ？Please help me

Comment: Did you actually try one of your plans? What was the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following approach should be more flexible ?
But the performance is poor.

```
brow_drivers = {
    ("ff", "firefox"): webdriver.Firefox,
    ("ie", "internet explorer"): webdriver.Ie,
    "edge": webdriver.Edge,
    "opera": webdriver.Opera,
   "phantomjs": webdriver.PhantomJS,
}

if remote_address is None:
    if browser in ("chrome", "Chrome"):
        mobile_emulation = {"deviceName": "Galaxy S5"}
        option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        option.add_experimental_option('w3c', False)
        option.add_experimental_option('mobileEmulation', mobile_emulation)
        dr = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option)
    else:
        dr = next(v for k, v in brow_drivers.items() if browser in k)()
```

Answer (score 1):

How about putting the various drivers in a dictionary; something like this?

```
drivers = {
    "firefox": webdriver.Firefox,
    "ie": webdriver.Ie,
    "opera": webdriver.Opera,
    "phantomjs": webdriver.PhantomJS,
    "edge": webdriver.Edge,
}
drivers["internet explorer"] = drivers["ie"]
drivers["ff"] = drivers["firefox"]

if remote_address is None:
    if browser in ("chrome", "Chrome"):
        mobile_emulation = {"deviceName": "Galaxy S5"}
        option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        option.add_experimental_option('w3c', False)
        option.add_experimental_option('mobileEmulation', mobile_emulation)
        dr = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option)
    else:
        dr = drivers[browser]()
```

Comment: Optimization plan 2 is feasible.